# unity c# prefab, scene and network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have two scene at unity.

if i make room or i join the room, the game make player(prefab) at second scene.

at first scene, i make room for network game in unity .

after i execute .exe file in window. so i can watch game screen and room list.

but when i make room or join the room i don't watch player prefab.

i found reason.

[image]

player prefab is created outside canvas.

if i drag the player in Canvas , i can see player on game view.

i want to create prefab in the canvas.

i used this methods.

[image]

thank you for reading this question

Answer (score 0):

You need additional script that make player a child of canvas.

EDIT Something like that (applied to player prefab):

```
public Canvas canvas; 
void Start()
{
 transform.parent = canvas.transform;
 Destroy(this);
}
```

Comment: i add script to player prefab. but i can't drag canvas  in player prefab inspector . it doesn't activation

Comment: then change `public Canvas canvas;` to `public transform canvas;`